# Understanding how class decorators work in Python

Tags: python, function, oop, decorator

I've got a problem with understanding how class decorators in Python work. In this case I want to write a decorator that counts how many times recursive function (searching for Greatest Common Divisor)  was called. I have a decorator:

```
class TrackCalls(object):

def __init__(self, func):
    self.func = func
    self.calls = 0

def __call__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    self.calls += 1
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

def called(self):
    return self.calls
```

and a function:

```
@TrackCalls
def NWD(a, b):

    if a > b:
        return NWD(a-b, b)
    elif b > a:
        return NWD(a, b-a)
    else:
        return a
```

and then I call them:

```
print(NWD(60,25)) #5
print(NWD.called()) #6
```

What is exactly happening with NWD function? As far as I know, decorators take a function and make another function, so in this case TrackCalls takes the function, makes an object of class TrackCalls and then by calling `NWD.called()` I basically call a method of TrackCalls object? When I run eg. `NWD(5,25)` after previous calls I get 11, so it looks like every time I call NWD I call TrackCalls object with some kind of static variable. If I were to decorate another recursive function with the same decorator, would they share `calls` variable?

Comment: Try it, and find out!

Comment: I'm honestly a little surprised this works. I would have thought it wouldn't count the recursion calls.

Answer (score 3):

I think your confusion can be traced back to the duck-typing concept of python. This refers to the idea that from an outside perspective there is no difference between a `function` [lets call it `func`] and an object (=instance) [lets call it `obj`] of a class with a `__call__` method. Both are `callable`, that is they may take arguments within parentheses an return something as in `func(args)` and `obj(args)` respectively . Of cause the difference is that as an object `obj` has state, that is it has instance variables (also often called fields).

In your example `calls` and `func` are fields of the `TrackCalls` class.
By decorating your `NWD` function with `@TrackCalls` you wrap `NWD` with an **instance** of `TrackCalls`. That is the name `NWD` is basically replaced with an instance of `TrackCalls` equivalent to calling `NWD = TrackCalls(NWD)`. The new instance is callable and as such behaves like the original function but as it is an object it also has state and can count the invocations of its `__call__` method. The calculation itself is delegated to the original implementation of `NWD` which is now stored in the `func` field.

To answer your question each function you decorate with `TrackCalls` will result in a new instance of `TrackCalls` **each with its own** state. But multiple calls to one decorated function **share** the state of that function.

Comment: I've been struggling with this thing for a while, but you made it clear to me, thank you very much :)